# I can not read a URL in Python3 that I can even open in Chrome

Tags: php, windows, url, urllib, python-3.7

I'm having a problem while tring to read data from a website using urllib in Python 3.  The script works with any other websites but it does not read the url https://servicios.siur.com.co/mapas/marks.php?ruta=T31.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://servicios.siur.com.co/mapas/marks.php?ruta=T31"

f = urlopen(url)
file = f.read()
print(file)
```

Can be a network problem?

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory>
```

How can I fix this problem with python 3 in Widnwos 10?

Thank you all

Comment: access the link above manually said the certificate has been revoked, that could be the problem.

Comment: It is really weird. It opens to me correctly. What browser are you using, catcon?

Comment: I use firefox v70.0

Comment: I just check the link with google chrome, verified that chrome can open the link without problem.

Comment: Thanks catcon. I can not open the the URL in Explorer. I guess that I need set the CA. How can I do it?